# Ubuntu 22.04 on Acer Aspire A514-54: excessive heat and battery drain during suspension

Tags: 22.04, suspend

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Acer Aspire A514-54 laptop, setting it up as a dual boot alongside Windows. While using Ubuntu I've encountered an issue with excessive heat and battery drain when I put the laptop in suspension mode.

Laptop specifications:

Model: Acer Aspire A514-54
  Processor: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz × 8
  Graphics: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
  OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

The problem is that when I suspend the laptop, it not only gets hot, but it also seems to be draining the battery rapidly. Just last night, I put the laptop in suspension, and by morning, it was already out of power.

I've tried adjusting power settings and updating the system, but the issue persists. Are there any workarounds or troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my **Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04**, Dell Inspiron 15 3000, where the deep suspend seems not to be supported. Even editing `/sys/power/mem_sleep` using sudo is not possible.
Updating the [Linux kernel](https://linuxhint.com/install-upgrade-latest-kernel-ubuntu-22-04/) reduced my battery drain much better for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1323142)

Comment: I just provided a hyperlink to get a better way to update the kernel which isn't an answer. Updating the kernel will reduce the battery drain and anyone can use any link or tutorials to do that.